# How to Serialise Dictionary<int, object> to JSON, but Ignore Key

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I have the following class property

```
public Dictionary<int, Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
```

When I serialize to JSON the dictionary key is being serialized as follows:

```
{
"results": {
    "id": "d875e165-4705-459e-8532-fca2ae811ae0",
    "arrival_date": "2019-02-16",
    "departure_date": "2019-02-17",
    "expires": "2019-01-17T17:11:23.2941604+00:00",
    "hotels": {
        "9036": {
            "hotel_id": 9036,
            "name": "Beach View Hotel",
            "address": null,
            "star_rating": 0,
            "review_score": 0,
            "phone_number": null,
            "website_url": null,
            "email_address": null,
            "channels": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Channel Name 0",
                    "offers": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "9049": {
            "hotel_id": 9049,
            "name": "City House Hotel",
            "address": null,
            "star_rating": 0,
            "review_score": 0,
            "phone_number": null,
            "website_url": null,
            "email_address": null,
            "channels": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Channel Name 0",
                    "offers": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "9107": {
            "hotel_id": 9107,
            "name": "Park Hotel",
            "address": null,
            "star_rating": 0,
            "review_score": 0,
            "phone_number": null,
            "website_url": null,
            "email_address": null,
            "channels": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Channel Name 1",
                    "offers": []
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "errors": []
}
```

}

Is it possible to remove somehow, maybe by class property attribute?

> "9036":

So the desired JSON becomes

```
"hotels": { "hotel_id": 9036, "name": "My Hotel Name",
```

Comment: Can you pls provide the desired JSON?

Comment: I've updated the question, but basically I don't want the JSON serializer to ignore the Dictionary key value.

Comment: Have you tried select and then serialize


`serialize(Hotels.select(x => x.value))`

Comment: @Chenna That's the exact opposite of what the OP wants

Comment: Please update your example to include **multiple hotels**. I am pretty sure you have a typo - since I think you are missing `[` and `]` in the JSON you want to generate.

Comment: Even better, please provide a [mcve] with sample inputs. Be sure to specify the **exact output** you want.

Comment: I've updated to include a full JSON response with multiple hotels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format `"hotels": { "hotel_id": 9036, "name": "My Hotel Name", ... },..` is not valid, but you can make it an array `"hotels": [ { "hotel_id": 9036, "name": "My Hotel Name", ... } ]`.

You can do so by marking your Dictionary with JsonIgnore and exposing a Collection of Hotels which contains Values from the Dictionary of Hotels.

For example,

```
var hotel = new Results
{
    id= "d875e165-4705-459e-8532-fca2ae811ae0",
    HotelDictionary = new Dictionary<int,Hotels> {
    [2323]=new Hotels{Id=2323,Name="Sample1"},
    [1323]=new Hotels{Id=1323,Name="Sample2"},
    }
};
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hotel,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Where Results and Hotels is defined as (please note i have ignored other properties to focus on dictionary, but you can add them in for your final solution).

```
public class Results
{

    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<int,Hotels> HotelDictionary { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("hotels")]
    public IEnumerable<Hotels> Hotels => HotelDictionary.Select(x=>x.Value);
}

public class Hotels
{
    [JsonProperty("hotel_id")]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Output

```
{
  "id": "d875e165-4705-459e-8532-fca2ae811ae0",
  "hotels": [
    {
      "hotel_id": 2323,
      "name": "Sample1"
    },
    {
      "hotel_id": 1323,
      "name": "Sample2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer but returned  return HotelDictionary.Select(x => x.Value).ToList() as a List instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because this JSON structure is not valid:

```
"hotels": { "hotel_id": 9036, "name": "My Hotel Name", ... }, { ... }
```

You can, however, select only the values and serialize that:

```
hotels.Values;
```

To get this:

```
"hotels": [ { "hotel_id": 9036, "name": "My Hotel Name", ... }, { ... } ]
```

Given that that's part of a class, you'll need a new model:

```
public class SomeName
{
    public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
}

var someName = new SomeName
{
    Hotels = hotels.Values.ToList();
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem may be that you need to add `hotel_id` as a property on the `Hotel` object.

Depending on where your data is coming from, this is probably a good idea anyways, not just in this case.